# How to send result from AsyncTask from Activity1 to Activity2

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

In my Activity1, I have an AsyncTask that uploads to the server. Once this task is started, I want to start Activity, without waiting for the completion of AsyncTask. When the AsyncTask from Activity1 is completed, I want to update something in Activity2. After doing some searching, I've found multiple references/examples of using interfaces. But I ran into the following problem:

OnUploadCompleted Interface

```
public interface OnUploadCompleted {
    void on UploadCompleted();
}
```

Activity2

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity implements OnUploadCompleted {
    // all the usual activity code

    @Override
    public void onUploadCompleted() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Upload Done", ....
    }
}
```

Activity1

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity {
    // all the usual activity code

    private class Upload extends AsyncTask<...> {
        OnUploadCompleted listener;

        public Upload(OnUploadCompleted listener) {
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        // skipping doInBackground task

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(...) {
            super.onPostExecute();
            listener.onUploadCompleted();
        }
    }

    void foo (...) {
        OnUploadCompleted listener = new Activity2();
        Upload upload = new Upload(listener);
        upload.execute();
        finish();
    }
}
```

The problem I have is in the foo() function. the listener is a new instance of Activity2 class, but Activity2 hasn't been created yet. It will be created by the parent activity of Activity1, after the finish(). So, when the listener is actually called, the activity that it's "connected" to is null. In the onUploadCompleted(), when Toast is called, the "this" is null.

Comment: you might want to consider using a background `service` instead of the asycTask. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: If you simply want to show a Toast, then pass the applicationContext to the AsyncTask, using that to show the Toast.

Comment: @Gary Kipnis check my answer...

Comment: @cYrixmorten - the Toast was just a test to see if I am able to talk to the 2nd Activity. I actually need to do much more than just Toast :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try sending Broadcasts to ACtivity2 from Activity1 when Activity1's AsyncTask completed...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public static final String ACTION_TASK_COMPLETED = "com.sample.project.action.ACTION_TASK_COMPLETED";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private class DoTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // please wait. I am doing work
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // yay... work completed...
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_TASK_COMPLETED);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
  }
}

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
private TaskReceiver taskReceiver;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(MainActivity.ACTION_TASK_COMPLETED);
    taskReceiver = new TaskReceiver();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(taskReceiver, intentFilter);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(taskReceiver);
}

private void onUploadImage() {
    // uploading completed... 
}

private class TaskReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        onUploadImage();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you Gopal. This worked. Just one question. If the upload in the AsyncTask happened to complete before the 2nd Activity had a chance to start, would the broadcast message be lost or still available for the 2nd Activity to be received? I don't think this is even possible, but just in case.

Comment: One more question related to AsyncTask, do they continue executing when the application itself is brought into the background (paused/stopped)?

Comment: first, if the Activity2 is not started (onCreate() is not executed), there will be no result even you sent broascast. means, before the Activity2 has started, Broastcast message will be last. 
second, AsyncTask continue it's execution as long as it's work is completed or your Application Context is in scope. task will be executing even your app is in background. if the user kills your app by swiping left in recent tasks, your AsyncTask also dies...